# How to clear values/strings for any input type such as text/password etc after submitting form in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Below is my code snippet for HTML,

```
<div>
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" (ngSubmit)="createUser(Username.value, Password.value)">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username..." #Username required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password..." #Password autocomplete="off" required>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

and below is .ts file.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'create-component',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/user-create.component.html'
})
export class CreateUserComponent {

  constructor() {
  }

  private createUser(Username, Password) {
    this.myService.createUser(Username, Password).subscribe(
        success => {
            console.log('User is created');
        },
        error => console.log('error')
    );
  }
}
```

so my requirement is after creating every user i want to clear textbox values by using one-way binding, i knew that there is another way to create a one method to set values to '' empty string using data members declared inside class. Here dont want to use any variable, in my code i am using one way binding(i.e. ref for input e.g. #Username) to just sent input values to my createUser function from UI.

Comment: Useful if you provide your template

Comment: are you using angular2 form ?

Comment: @SubtainIshfaq, yes i am using Angular2 form

Comment: You can use https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html to create form which is having form reset method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for this link, and below is working change-set for my code to reset control values after submitting form. 
1. Import library in app.module.ts file for, 
    `import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'` 
2. Add formgroup to your form tag, e.g. 
    `<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" (ngSubmit)="createUser(Username.value, Password.value)" [formGroup]="myForm">`. 
3. add 'formControlName' attribute to your input control, 
    `<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username..." formControlName="Username" #Username required>` and same for other input controls. 
4. Changes in user component.ts file, 
    `import {FormGroup, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';` 
and initiate instance for FormGroup in your constructor() or in ngOnInit() event, 
    `this.myForm = new FormGroup({
            Username: new FormControl(),
            Password: new FormControl()
        });`. 
5. Finally call reset method wherever you want to reset the control values, 
    `this.myForm.reset();`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular2 form , you can't reset it till now but there is work-around shared in [this answere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39105969/3476801) .

**Edit As per the comments :** We have reset function in formGroup
Visit the link below :

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#reset-anchor

Comment: that's old answer for previous angular version now `FormGroup` is having `reset` method. check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html

Comment: Thanks for this link, and below is working chnageset for my code to reset control values after submitting form.