# How to reset validators in reactive form in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-forms

I have using angular Reactive from. But when i reset the form after submitting it, the validators being in invalid and showing invalid form style. 
How to make the validators reset ? 
Can anybody help me to sort this out.

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset form validation on submission of the form in ANGULAR 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608361/how-to-reset-form-validation-on-submission-of-the-form-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 3):

Hi can you try like this

```
this.form.reset()
```

after submitting can you use both methods

```
this.form.updateValueAndValidity()
```

Comment: it wont reset the validators.

Comment: I am using material input box.

Comment: this does not work in reactive forms with material inputs it keeps showing in red the fields that have just been clear or reset

Comment: @Robert Well I am no the OP, I have tried this answer and is still showing in red al the requiered inputs after reseting it using this

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [Resetting a form in Angular 2 after submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655922/resetting-a-form-in-angular-2-after-submit)

**>= RC.6**

Support resetting forms and maintain a `submitted` state.

```
console.log(this.form.submitted);
```

```
this.form.reset()
```

or

```
this.form = new FormGroup()...;
```

**importat update**

To set the Form controls to a state when the form is created, like validators, some additional measurements are necessary

In the view part of the form (html) add an `*ngIf` to show or hide the form

```ts
<form *ngIf="showForm"
```

In the component side of the form (*.ts) do this

```ts
  showForm:boolean = true;

  onSubmit(value:any):void {
    this.showForm = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
    this.reset()
      this.showForm = true;
    });
  }
```

Here is a more detailed example:

```ts
export class CreateParkingComponent implements OnInit {
  createParkingForm: FormGroup ;
  showForm = true ;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private parkingService: ParkingService,
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {

      this.prepareForm() ;
  }

  prepareForm() {
    this.createParkingForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'name': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])],
      'company': ['', Validators.minLength(5)],
      'city': ['', Validators.required],
      'address': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)])],
      'latitude': [''],
      'longitude': [''],
      'phone': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(7)])],
      'pictureUrl': [''],
      // process the 3 input values of the maxCapacity'
      'pricingText': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)])],
      'ceilingType': ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  resetForm(form: FormGroup) {
    this.prepareForm();
  }

  createParkingSubmit() {
    // Hide the form while the submit is done
    this.showForm = false ;

    // In this case call the backend and react to the success or fail answer

    this.parkingService.create(p).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.snackBar.open('Parqueadero creado', 'X', {duration: 3000});
        setTimeout(() => {
          //reset the form and show it again
          this.prepareForm();
            this.showForm = true;
          });
      }
      , error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.showForm = true ;
        this.snackBar.open('ERROR: al crear Parqueadero:' + error.message);
      }
      );
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/8avkh0?p=preview)

**original <= RC.5**
Just move the code that creates the form to a method and call it again after you handled submit:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'form-component',
  template: `
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)" [ngFormModel]="form">
       <input type="test" ngControl="name">
       <input type="test" ngControl="email">
       <input type="test" ngControl="username">
       <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
    <div>name: {{name.value}}</div>
    <div>email: {{email.value}}</div>
    <div>username: {{username.value}}</div>
`
})
class FormComponent {

  name:Control;
  username:Control;
  email:Control;

  form:ControlGroup;

  constructor(private builder:FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.name = new Control('', Validators.required);
    this.email = new Control('', Validators.required);
    this.username = new Control('', Validators.required);

    this.form = this.builder.group({
      name: this.name,
      email: this.email,
      username: this.username
    });
  }

  onSubmit(value:any):void {
    // code that happens when form is submitted
    // then reset the form
    this.reset();
  }

  reset() {
    this.createForm();
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/FSX6EG?p=preview)