# Notification upon Form Reset Event?

Tags: angular, angular-template-form

Is there a way to get notified when a form is reset via the formReset method?

I have a directive that injects the form and I can get notified when the form is submitted or reset via a reset button but I cannot figure out a way to get notified when formRest is called on ngForm.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appForm]'
})
export class FormDirective implements OnDestroy {
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(form: NgForm) {
    this.subscription = form.ngSubmit.subscribe(() => {
      console.log('submitted');
    });
    form.onReset = () => {
      console.log('reset');
    };
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

Using the directive like

```
<form appForm #form="ngForm">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
  <button type="button" (click)="form.resetForm()">Angular reset</button>
</form>
```

Is there a way to notify my directive that the resetForm method has been called?

Demo at StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-adymlf?file=src/app/form.directive.ts

Comment: not sure why onReset is not been triggered. But as an workaround you can try doing `<button type="button" (click)="form.resetForm(); form.onReset()">Angular reset</button>`

Comment: I don't want the consumers of my library to have to manually call the reset function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resetting a form in Angular 2 after submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655922/resetting-a-form-in-angular-2-after-submit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [w3schools onReset event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onreset.asp), "reset" event is only triggered when the `<input type="reset">`. This is probably a default behaviour in browsers.

Angular's `resetForm()` and `reset()` doesn't actually trigger the reset event. It simply programatically *revert* the values of the form. `resetForm()` allows you to reset the submitted status of the angular form and also define intial values for the form to be reset to by passing in an object like this:  `resetForm({})`.

This can be proven by adding a `@HostListener('reset')` in your attribute directive to listen for reset events. When `form.resetForm()` and `form.reset()` is called (or rather, clicked), reset event is not triggered at all.

---

#### Listening for clicks in Attribute Directives for buttons

To work around this, you can simply use `<button type="reset">`? But if it doesn't suit your use case, and you need to use `<button type="button">` and still detect a reset event then you can probably add another @HostListener to listen for click events for input type of buttons:

```js
@HostListener('click', ['$event.target']) onFormClick(btn: HTMLButtonElement){
  // console.log(btn)
  if(btn.type == "button"){
    console.log("detected click event on 'Angular reset' button, triggering reset event!");
    this.form.onReset();
  }
}
```

---

#### Detecting when NgForm's resetForm() is called (EDIT)

```js
//to store original resetForm()
resetFormFunc;

constructor(private form: NgForm, private elRef: ElementRef) {

   ...

   this.resetFormFunc = form.resetForm; //assigning resetForm function to "store" it.

   //"Override" resetForm(), and call original resetForm() in the middle
   form.resetForm = () => {
     console.log("detected calling of resetForm()!");
     this.resetFormFunc.apply(form, arguments); //actually call form.resetForm()
     console.log("my additional code");
   }
}
```

When "Angular Reset" is clicked:
[image]

[**#2 Forked Stackblitz ⚡**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hgkhah)

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem I am having is that the consumers of my library create the buttons, my directive is what needs to be notified of the reset happening. It is all good when a reset button can be used but that resets all the bindings to null, sometimes you need to use resetForm to pass in a model but I cannot find a way of letting my directive be notified of this happening. There is now way I am going to ask my consumers to start doing this kind of thing.

Comment: ahh my bad, I misunderstood your question. What if you tried to save the original `form.resetForm()` in a variable, and then override `resetForm()` before calling back the original resetForm(), would that work? Something like in the 2nd stackblitz I have edited in ...

Comment: Overriding the resetForm method lets me do exactly what I need