# reset reactive form Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to reset my form after sending the data. I've almost done it except for the detail of the validation of the mail format. I should mention that `this.form.reset()` does not work for me.

[image]

Any idea how to fix it?

```js
<form [formGroup]="forma" (ngSubmit)="agregarDomiciliario()" novalidate>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Valor de la propiedad" formControlName="valorPropiedad">
        <mat-error *ngIf="forma.controls['valorPropiedad'].invalid">{{ errorValorPropiedad() }}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div class="row">
        <mat-form-field class="col-md-6">
          <input matInput placeholder="Ingresa tu email" formControlName="email">
          <mat-error *ngIf="forma.controls['email'].invalid">{{ errorEmail() }}</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field class="col-md-6">
          <input matInput placeholder="Ingresa tu celular" formControlName="celular">
          <mat-error *ngIf="forma.controls['celular'].invalid">{{ errorCelular() }}</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <mat-checkbox class="small" formControlName="acepta">Acepto los términos y condiciones</mat-checkbox>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!forma.valid">Cotizar <i class="fas fa-arrow-right ml-2"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

```js
forma: FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) { 
    this.forma = fb.group ({
      valorPropiedad: [ '', Validators.required ],
      email : ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email] ],
      celular: [ '', Validators.required ],
      acepta : [ false, Validators.requiredTrue ]
    });
  }
  
  agregarDomiciliario() {
    console.log(this.forma.value);
    this.forma.setValue({
      valorPropiedad : [''],
      email: [''],
      celular: [''],
      acepta : false,
    });
  }
```

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788215/angular-material-reseting-reactiveform-shows-validation-error/49789012#49789012

Comment: Thanks @Pengyy this worked for me. I will respond with a reference to this post.

Answer (score 1):

Your method invoked on the `(ngSubmit)` event dispatches an invalid `setValue` call. If you want your form to match the values defined in your constructor it should look like this:

```
agregarDomiciliario() {
  this.forma.setValue({
    valorPropiedad : '',
    email: '',
    celular: '',
    acepta : false,
  });
}
```

Otherwise you set the `valorPropiedad`, `email` and `celular` values to `['']` (array with a single empty string) and not `''` (empty string).

Comment: If I do this, the validations are activated by default, I do not understand why but it happens.

Comment: Add `touched` check to your `*ngIf` expressions.  `<mat-error *ngIf="forma.controls['email'].invalid && form.controls['email'].touched">`