# reset reactive from / value null

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular-material2

I am implementing the following solution to reset my reactive form: [Angular Material: Reseting reactiveform shows validation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788215/angular-material-reseting-reactiveform-shows-validation-error/49789012#49789012)

At the first sending the form works well and resets well, but immediately after when I fill in the fields and do the 2nd. I send the fields `fecha` and `estado` appear as `null`, the others all ok.

I'm working with angular material and Firestore.

FormGroup:

```
this.forma = fb.group ({
  valorPropiedad: [ 100000, Validators.required ],
  nombre: [ '', Validators.required ],
  email : [ '', [Validators.required, Validators.email] ],
  celular: [ '', Validators.required ],
  acepta : [ false, Validators.requiredTrue ],
  fecha: [ firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() ],
  estado: [ false ]
});
```

Function:

```
agregarDomiciliario() {
  this.fs.addDomiciliario(this.forma.value);
  this.form.resetForm(this.forma);
}
```

Form html:

```
 <form #form="ngForm" [formGroup]="forma" (ngSubmit)="agregarDomiciliario()" novalidate>
...

</form>
```

Comment: try  using   this.ngForm.reset();

Comment: I already tried, in fact the form is reset but activates the validators, and apart it maintains the problems described in the question.