# Can't seem to reset my forms without errors

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

So I've been looking over some other posts here that talk about resetting your reactive form on angular but it doesn't work for me. Sure, the form's value gets reset but the form itself is marked red but no error message is shown. I would like for that to be gone as well.

#### The typescript of the component where the form is shown in

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-comment',
  templateUrl: './comment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comment.component.css']
})
export class CommentComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('comments') comments: Comment[];
  @Input('imageId') imageId: number;
  public messageForm: FormGroup;
  private _user: string;
  public loggedInUser: User;

  constructor(
    private _commentDataService: CommentDataService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private _authService: AuthenticationService,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private _snackBar: MatSnackBar
  ) {
    this.messageForm = this.fb.group({
      message: [
        '',
        [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(75)]
      ]
    });
  }

  getErrorMessage(error: any) {
    if (error.required) {
      return 'is required';
    } else if (error.minlength) {
      return `need at least ${error.minlength.requiredLength} characters`;
    } else if (error.maxlength) {
      return `max length is ${error.maxlength.requiredLength}`;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._authService.user$.subscribe(usr => (this._user = usr));
    this._authService.loggedInUser$.subscribe(user => {
      this.loggedInUser = user;
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this._user) {
      this._commentDataService
        .postComment(
          this.imageId,
          new Comment(
            this.loggedInUser.firstName + ' ' + this.loggedInUser.lastName,
            this.messageForm.value.message,
            new Date(),
            this.imageId,
            this.loggedInUser.id
          )
        )
        .subscribe(com => {
          console.log(com);
          this.comments.push(com);
          this.messageForm.reset({ message: '' });
        });
    } else {
      this.openSnackBar('You need to be logged in to send a message.');
    }
  }

  private openSnackBar(message: string) {
    this._snackBar.open(message, 'Close', { duration: 2000 });
  }

  isAuthor(comment: Comment): boolean {
    if (this.loggedInUser) {
      return comment.visitorId === this.loggedInUser.id;
    }
    return false;
  }

  openChangeDialog(comment: Comment) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ChangeCommentComponent, {
      width: '300px',
      data: {
        comment,
        array: this.comments,
        index: this.comments.indexOf(comment)
      }
    });
  }

  openDeleteDialog(comment: Comment) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DeleteCommentComponent, {
      width: '300px',
      height: '200px',
      data: { comment, array: this.comments }
    });
  }
}
```

#### The HTML where that presents the form

```html
<div class="overflow">
  <div
    fxLayout="row"
    fxLayoutAlign="space-between"
    *ngFor="let comment of comments"
  >
    <div>
      <div class="commentDiv" data-cy="comments">
        <span class="user left">{{ comment.author }}: </span>
        <span>{{ comment.content }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="iconDiv right" *ngIf="isAuthor(comment)">
        <mat-icon class="edit" (click)="openChangeDialog(comment)"
          >edit</mat-icon
        ><mat-icon class="delete" (click)="openDeleteDialog(comment)"
          >delete</mat-icon
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<form [formGroup]="messageForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" data-cy="commentForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input
      matInput
      aria-label="Message"
      placeholder="Message"
      type="text"
      class="browser-default"
      formControlName="message"
    />
    <mat-error
      *ngIf="
        messageForm.get('message')['errors'] &&
        messageForm.get('message').touched
      "
    >
      {{ getErrorMessage(messageForm.get('message')['errors']) }}
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-raised-button type="submit" [disabled]="!messageForm.valid">
    <mat-icon>send</mat-icon>
  </button>
</form>
```

More clearly: the user can add a comment to a picture. When he does and he calls the POST method (inside the OnSubmit()), I would like the form to clear. When I call `this.messageForm.reset()`, it does clear the form but also puts it in a nonvalid state (because it get's outlined in red, but no error message is shown underneath). Whilst if there is an error that the user generated byb not respecting the validations that I have put in place, the form will also be red but the error message will be shown in a `<small>` tag, generated by Material (the `<mat-error>`). I'm looking for a way to reset the form whithout it throwning errors.

Comment: Can you please make it more clear about `the form's value gets reset but the form itself is marked red but no error message is shown.`

Comment: could you show how you setup your form controls

Comment: @TonyNgo I've updated the question, hopefully you'll understand it better now.

Comment: @Miaan What exactly do you mean with the setup? (I've added the rest of the ts file if that helps)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Material: Reseting reactiveform shows validation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788215/angular-material-reseting-reactiveform-shows-validation-error)

Answer (score 0):

So a good way to do this would be to use the reset() method more effectively.
I would suggest you create a property `isSubmitted` and set it to true just inside your submit method. 
(Sidenote: Since it's just one input, I don't see why you called messageForm.value.message though.)

Then, where you are calling the reset method, wrap that in an if statement to check if `isSubmitted === true`, you can add more conditions as you see fit.... See the code snippet attached:

```
onSubmit() {
 this.isSubmitted = true;
  if (this._user) {
    this._commentDataService
    .postComment(
      this.imageId,
       new Comment(
        this.loggedInUser.firstName + ' ' + this.loggedInUser.lastName,
        this.messageForm.value,
        new Date(),
        this.imageId,
        this.loggedInUser.id
      )
    )
    .subscribe(com => {
      console.log(com);
      this.comments.push(com);

     if (this.isSubmitted.true) {`
        this.messageForm.reset ({
          message: { value: null, disabled: true } 
     });
   }
 }`
```

Comment: it almost works, the problem now it that it puts [object Object] inside those fields (just a you would see in local storage when you don't stringify an object). Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: That's not right. 
Try this: after you call the reset method, set  `value` to an empty string, instead of null, remember null is an object. Drop a line if this does not work, I will hang around.

Comment: Ive done this:
`this.messageForm.reset({ message: { value: null } });`
`this.messageForm.value.message = '';`
but it still doesn't work. It keeps [object Object] in there. Now I can place `message:''`in there but then the error gets thrown again. I actually just need a way to deselect or remove the cursor form that field after I posted

Comment: setting `disabled` to true would render the form inaccessible on submission and please, you don't have to call `this.messageForm.value.message`, that will not work... 

It's setting object there because you are not handling the value of message formcontrol.

Can you spin the code up in a test environment like stackblitz?

Comment: But i don't want that they only can send one message and then disable it. I'm setting up a stackbiltz (kinda hard because I've a lot of dependencies on other files)

Comment: That's no problem though, you can just set the disabled to false

Comment: Can i postpone this question for a while? I'm in my exam period atm @BenedictBincom

Comment: Please do, send a message when you're done. Good luck with your exams