# Angular material reset form after submit

Tags: javascript, validation, angular-material, submit

I use angular material and I have a form with reactive validation.

I want to reset my form after submitting, my issue is after submitting I see my errors appears in the form.

input example :

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Prénom</mat-label>
  <input matInput name="prenom" formControlName="prenom">
  <mat-error *ngIf="f.prenom.hasError('required') && submitted">
    Ce champ est obligatoire
  </mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="f.prenom.errors?.maxlength && !f.prenom.hasError('required')">
    le prénom ne peut pas dépasser 20 caractères
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

I tried to add a submitted variable and  this.myForm.markAsUntouched() but dosesn't work

```
onSubmit() {
  this.submitted = true;
  if (this.myForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }
  alert('Form Submitted succesfully!!!\n Check the values in browser console.');
  console.table(this.myForm.value);
  this.submitted = false;
  this.myForm.reset();
  this.myForm.markAsUntouched();
}
```

With the submitted variable I see the message error disappear(the yellow section below) but not the border and red color.

[image]

Do you guys have any ideas to solve that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this by putting #formDirective="ngForm" in the form tag

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #formDirective="ngForm">
```

And declare

```
@ViewChild('formDirective') private formDirective: NgForm;
```

You can then put .resetForm()

Comment: This may not work after angular 10. Try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788215/angular-material-reseting-reactiveform-shows-validation-error/71108302#71108302