# angular reset reactive form

Tags: angular, reset, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to reset my form after it is sent, but only the value is set to null.

*component.html*

```
  <div *ngIf="!loading" fxLayout="row" class="note-textarea">
    <form  fxFlex fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" [formGroup]="noteForm">
      <mat-form-field fxFlex>
        <textarea matInput #note rows="1" maxlength="100" placeholder="Note" formControlName="description"></textarea>
        <mat-hint align="end">{{note.value?.length || 0}}/100</mat-hint>
        <mat-error *ngIf="noteForm.get('description').errors && noteForm.get('description').touched">description is required</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div fxFlex>
        <button mat-stroked-button class="save-btn" (click)="insertNote()">Save</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

*component.ts*

```
  noteForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    description: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
  })
```

```
 insertNote() {
   // bunch of code 

      this.noteForm.reset();

    }
  }
```

the problem is that input field is mark as dirty as you can see below:

[image]

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608361/how-to-reset-form-validation-on-submission-of-the-form-in-angular-2

Comment: @Ivilin Stouanov, Read about using `resetForm` or `type=reset`.

Comment: reset will resets the FormGroup by marks all descendants are marked pristine and untouched, and the value of all descendants to null. 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with button `type="reset"` option

```
<button type="reset">Reset</button>
```

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-1ij7xw)

Comment: this wil reset the from but he try reset after  click save and run insertNote method from the component body

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ngForm` to do so

`In your Html file`

```
<form  fxFlex fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" [formGroup]="noteForm" #noteForm="ngForm">
```

`In your ts file`

```
 @ViewChild('noteForm', { static: true }) noteForm: NgForm;
//to reset form
this.noteForm.resetForm();
```

Replace name accordingly in your HTML and TS files.

Answer (score 0):

you can use formGroup **reset** method like this `(click)="noteForm.reset()"` and this method will marks all descendants are marked **pristine** and **untouched**, and the value of all descendants to null.

*example*

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <input placeholder="description..." type="text" formControlName="description" ><br/><br/>

    <div
        *ngIf="form.get('description').hasError('required') && (form.get('description').dirty || form.get('description').touched) ">

        description is required

    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="insertNote()">Add </button> &nbsp;
    <button type="button" (click)="form.reset()">reset </button>

</div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-value-validators-wrwznv)

with angular material you don't need to check if the controls is touched

```
   <mat-error *ngIf="noteForm.get('description').hasError('required')">
       description is required
   </mat-error>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fzv2s2)

> I don't use this `<button type="reset">Reset</button>` because most the time I want to reset the form from the component and sometimes I want to pass initial value after reset

Answer (score -1):

```
for (let control in this.form.controls) {
  this.form.controls[control].setErrors(null);
}
```